# Can’t use/format a new WD Blue 1TB (WD10EZEX) hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, format

I’ve been having problems installing a hard drive in my new desktop computer, which is booting off of an SSD. It is [a WD Blue 1TB Desktop Hard Disk Drive - 7200 RPM SATA 6 Gb/s 64MB Cache 3.5 Inch - WD10EZEX](http://www.wdc.com/global/products/specs/?driveID=1092&language=1). I have tried going into disk management to format it, but it says “No media” on the disk. In the properties, it indicates that there is no memory on the device. I also tried [Disk Wipe’s utility](http://diskwipe.org), but it failed to format the drive. I have tried running it through a SATA-to-USB cable (which works fine with a different memory drive), and inside my computer tower through regular SATA-to-SATA ports. Trying to connect the drive to another computer (Windows 8) via the SATA-to-USB cable led to the same results as the computer I want to use the drive on. I can’t find any answers to fix this on the web.

The motherboard is [Gigabyte LGA 1150 Intel H97 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 Micro ATX DDR3 1600 LGA 1150 Motherboards GA-H97M-HD3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KRUX0X2). Also, the computer is running on a new installation of Windows 10 Education.

As a note, I had the same exact problems with the same brand drive and figured it was just a faulty drive. So I exchanged it to only have the same exact problems. I can’t find any indications of anyone else having problems with this brand of drive, either and it is [very highly rated on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0088PUEPK).

Can anyone give me some suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a desktop PC. If so, what's your motherboard? Have you tried different SATA ports?

Comment: I have added the requested information. Please ask if more details would be helpful.

Comment: I'm hesitant to believe both WD drives that I've tried are useless, but maybe I'll end up having just to return it and try a different brand. :/

Comment: As I first commented, have you tried another SATA port?

Comment: Have you tried it on a  port you know works? Some desktops might have sata ports that share pci channels with some other device.

Comment: I thought one SATA port and the USB-to-SATA port was enough testing, but by user3614411 and Journeyman Geek's suggestions, I went ahead and tried hooking it through the SATA port that my SSD was using and thus confirmed to be working. Slightly embarrassing, but now the hard drive looks to be working fine. Thanks everyone for your input! :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is 8+ years old was clearly self-solved by the end user in a way that is idiosyncratic to their setup/.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the SATA mode to IDE. That worked for me on an AMD A88X motherboard which failed to recognise my hard drive.

Regarding 'broken' drives, it may be possible to restore them to working order by running DEBUG from within DOS and entering the following commands:

```
a 100
int 13

rax
0301
rbx
0200
f 200 l 200 0
rcx
0001
rdx
0080
p
q
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each line, including the blank 3rd line. It takes just seconds but blanks the first hard drive in the system. To avoid any mistakes connect *only the faulty drive while using this procedure*.

To use this you will of course have to boot from a floppy, CD, DVD or flash drive pre-loaded with DOS.